# Normalized correlation

Tags: python, correlation

I have trouble with the use of the normalized correlation. I am using python to plot the different plots, such as correlation, normalized correlation and auto-correlation.

When I use my own defined function with a sinus it works well, but when I try the Wikipedia example with a triangle and a box wave the normalized correlation does not work anymore.

This is the code I use (only the functions):

```
def crosscor(sig, known):
    ans = np.array([])
    temp = 0
    for i in range(len(sig)-len(known)):
        for j in range(len(known)):
            temp += sig[i+j]*known[j]
        ans = np.append(ans, temp)
        temp = 0
    return ans



def normcrosscor(sig, known):
    ans = np.array([])
    temp = 0
    x2 = 0
    y2 = 0
    for i in range(len(sig)-len(known)):
        for j in range(len(known)):
            x2 += (sig[i+j]-np.mean(sig[i:i+len(known)]))**2
            y2 += (known[j]-np.mean(known))**2
        sigx = (1/len(known)*x2)**(1/2)
        sigy = (1/len(known)*y2)**(1/2)
        for j in range(len(known)):
            if sigx != 0 and sigy != 0:
                temp += (sig[i+j]-np.mean(sig[i:i+len(known)]))*(known[j]-np.mean(known))/(sigx*sigy)            
            else:
                temp += 0
        temp = 1/len(known)*temp
        ans = np.append(ans, temp)
        x2 = 0
        y2 = 0
        temp = 0
    return ans  

def autocor(sig):
    x = sig
    y = sig
    ans = np.array([])
    y = np.lib.pad(y, (len(sig), len(sig)), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0))
    for t in range(len(y)-len(sig)+1):
        s = 0
        for i in range(len(x)):
            s += x[i]*y[i+t]
        ans = np.append(ans, s)   
    return ans
```

When I try this with a sinus my result is as follow:

[image]

And when I use a triangle wave and a blok wave to compare the signals I get:

[image]

I expect that the normalized correlation would also give me a result that has a maximum near 100.

Can somebody help me?